# Java Class cleanest/most efficient way to store a lot of properties

Tags: java, class

I'm coding a video game related project and have a Gun class representing each gun. We're going to have 30 or so unique guns in all and their settings will be read from a file to allow for easily configurable values. Each gun has 70-80 unique properties. There are 4-5 settings detailing their appearance, 5 settings having to do with them reloading (their clip size, how long it takes, what ammo it takes), 10 or so settings having to do with how much damage they do to other players, and so on, up to 80 or so unique settings that are different for each gun. Furthermore, about 30 of these settings are optional meaning they don't apply to every gun (for example, time between full auto shots doesn't apply to a semi auto gun and aim down sights properties don't apply to select guns that don't have sights)

I'm having trouble storing all this information in a Gun class in a way that's readable and fast (these values will be accessed quite frequently so loading from file every time seems inefficient). It's hard to find any good way to use inheritance for many of these because there's a ton of different combinations of properties (guns vary by fire type, whether or not they can be zoomed or have a scope, etc)

Currently I have different properties related to the same thing in their own settings classes, with each gun shaving 7 different settings classes holding their related settings, as shown:

````
    protected final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String type;
    private final ItemCategory tier;

    private final AppearanceSettings appearanceSettings;
    private final ReloadSettings reloadSettings;
    private final ShootingSettings shootingSettings;
    private final AimingSettings aimingSettings;
    private final DamageSettings damageSettings;
    private final BulletImpactSettings impactSettings;
    private final SoundSettings soundSettings;```
````

I'm not sure if there is a lot of overhead doing something like this, where there are ~30*7=210 classes in memory just holding variables, or if accessing said variables is slower.

One of the other approaches I can think of is just having 80 or so instance variables in the gun class, but readability would obviously be quite poor. An 80 parameter constructor would especially be a nightmare.

I was also thinking about having an enum listing all the properties and having a Map in the gun class that way only relevant properties need to be set for each gun which could save space? I don't know if this would slow down access however.

Sorry to ramble a bit but I think I got my problem across - what's the best way to store so many properties in a readable and efficient way? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need multiple `Gun` classes, but you also need to do a first-class job of normalizing your data.

Comment: I'd use JSON for the file format, and use a JSON parser to read the properties.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to do a first-class job on designing your classes using inheritance and design patterns. I am providing you some suggestions.

> I'm not sure if there is a lot of overhead doing something like this, where there are ~30*7=210 classes in memory just holding variables, or if accessing said variables is slower.

I wouldn't worry about the memory. Let's assume that you have 30 classes with 80 properties each, and on average a property is a String of size 10. A String with a length of 10 characters is about 30 bytes in memory. So 30 x 80 x 30 = 72KB (rough estimate), which is nothing for an average RAM capacity. Accessing the variables in memory is basically instant.

Regarding the persistence, if the values are going to change frequently I suggest to use a database. In this way you don't need to implement the logic to map the files into Java classes but you delegate it to JDBC.

> An 80 parameter constructor would especially be a nightmare.

I agree and I suggest to stick with your current solution. You can use a factory which given the settings create the Gun class. Abstract Factory pattern might be a good fit here.